# How can I make the changes done by a shell script permanent?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

How can I make the changes done by a shell script be permanent, even when the script terminates?

E.g.: script.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
cd dir2
pwd
```

Using this script:

```
cd dir1
script.sh
pwd
```

I get:

```
dir2
dir1
```

How can I stay in dir2 after the script terminates?

Comment: The script is executed in a subshell. You could use a function instead of a script, which could be executed in the same shell. Would that be suitable?

Comment: If you can make an example as simple as mine, I can tell you.

Comment: or "source" the script, and for heaven's sake, don't bother with the sh-bang.  e.g:   $ source script.sh    OR    $ . script.sh      either of these execute the "script" in the current shell.

Comment: The function could be `cd_pwd () { cd dir2; pwd; }` then your script could be `cd dir1; cd_pwd; pwd`.

Comment: The working directory of the process that executes the `cd` is "permanently" changed (which is to say, until either the process terminates or another chdir is executed.)  You need to reword the question.

Comment: Tom Fenech, and William Pursell comments are true: In UNIX, a process can not change its parent current working directory ever. Use a function, or and alias, or source the code containing the instructions from your shell as stated by Marty McGowan.

Comment: @MartyMcGowan: If you can copy your comment as an answer, I would pick it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`script.sh` is executed in a child process ("subshell"), and changing working directory in a child process doesn't affect working directory of parent process.

To change directory with something that looks like "a script", you have at least 3 possibilities:

- setting an alias; suitable for interactive work with shell; not your case, as far as I understand;
- writing a shell function instead of `script.sh`, see an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/874542/2731799);
- run `script.sh` in the current process using `source` or simply `.`

Example of the last:

```
source script.sh
```

or

```
. script.sh
```

More on `source` command [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-bsd-unix-source-command/).

And there is another really weird possibility, see here: [change working directory of caller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5956076/2731799). Nevertheless, don't take it too serious, consider like a very geeky joke for programmers.